# How do I take a dictionary input in the form a:123,b:12,c:213 in Python

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

```
s = raw_input()
a = dict(map(lambda l: l.split(':'), s.splitlines(',')))
print a
```

How do I take a dictionary input in the form `a:123,b:12,c:213` in Python 2?

Comment: Format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calling `splitline` your code will cause a value error

```
s = raw_input()
a = dict(map(lambda l: l.split(':'), s.split(',')))
print a
```

The above code will create a dictionary from your input. If you want the values to be of the keys to be integers add the following line:

```
for key in a:
    a[key] = int(a[key])
```